# What happens if a Runnable executed several times in an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

What happens if a thread has been executed same time more than once. Lets say I have thread like

```
private Runnable mySampleThread() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //something is going on here.

        }
    };
}
```

And I created an `ExecutorService` with fixed thread pool of 10. What happens if I execute `mySampleThread` 10 times in this `ExecutorService`.
Something like below,

```
ExecutorService mySampleExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
while (i <= 10) {
    mySampleExecutor.execute(mySampleThread);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: did you try it? what is happening? first try it

Comment: `Runnable` is not `Thread`. It's just a plain Java object with one method. All that happened is this method got executed more than once.

Comment: "What happens if .." is somewhat broad. Narrow it down. Mention what you expect, what you don't and what actually happens (by running your code first). It seems you are hinting at effects of multiple threads being spawned from the same Runnable object.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is very simple. Executor will execute `Runnable` object (it's not the Thread object) as described in documentation [Interface Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

> Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

Basically, Executor will pick up one thread of it's internal pool (ThreadPoolExecutor), assign runnable to it a execute `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly elaborate your problem or query.

Nevertheless, assuming that you are calling the method "mySampleThread()" without missing brackets. This method actually returns a new Runnable object every time, so you are passing a new runnable all 10 times to executor. And it means you are submitting 10 different tasks to executor. So if executor creates different thread for every task (that depends upon its implementation), then whatever you code inside run() will be executed 10 times in 10 different threads.

And as described in other answers, the runnable object being passed to executor is not a thread.

Hope it clarifies.

By the way, you may try running the program.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers clearly state, there will be as many new threads as the number of calls (might be less due to used executor, I'm focusing on `Runnable` reusage, limiting number of threads with executor is well explained in other answers). All of them created with single `Runnable` object.

What's worth mentioning, and I personally made use of this quite a few times - this is one of the ways to share data between multiple threads as all of these threads share `Runnable` that was used for creation. Synchronization issues come into play at this point, but that's another story.

Here's code to show the typical usage and the aforementioned synchronization problem.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

class MySynchronizedThread implements Runnable {
    public int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            synchronized (this) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class RunnableTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyThread runnableObject = new MyThread();
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ex.execute(runnableObject);
        }


        ex.shutdown();
        ex.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        System.out
                .println("Without synchronization: " + runnableObject.counter);

        MyThread runnableSynchronizedObject = new MyThread();
        ExecutorService ex2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ex2.execute(runnableSynchronizedObject);
        }

        ex2.shutdown();
        ex2.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("Without synchronization: "
                + runnableSynchronizedObject.counter);

    }
}
```

Comment: _there will be as many new threads as the number of calls._  No.  The whole point of using an executor service is to _not_ create a new thread for every new task.

Comment: @jameslarge i don't think that's the **whole** point. Also this statement is true both for OPs example and for mine, so yeah, there will be as many threads as executions.

Comment: @zubergu your example indeed explains the synchronization however, I don't see it as anyway relevant to the question. You are passing same object to executor and that's you need to take care of concurrency.

Comment: Well yeah, but that's because your example uses the literal `5` in two different places (The OP's example uses `10`).  If you changed the loop counter to go to 5000, but still left the size of the thread pool at 5, then it would never create more than five threads.

Comment: @RahulWinner I can't agree with that statement. As clearly mentioned, that's example of why would anyone want to reuse Runnable object. Clearly OP is novice, so I decided to include the most typical problem he would bump into when going that road, thus preventing from seeing another question about that issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no differences in `mySampleExecutor.execute(mySampleThread);`, `mySampleThread` method return a new `Runnable object.` every thread will have it's own [Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6)